# How to make the program run again after unexpected exit in Python?

Tags: python, irc

I'm writing an IRC bot in Python, due to the alpha nature of it, it will likely get unexpected errors and exit.

What's the techniques that I can use to make the program run again?

Comment: I just noticed that my answer contained something incorrect: “generally, 0 is returned in case of error” should be “generally, 1 is returned in case of error”. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sys.exit()` to tell that the program exited abnormally (generally, 1 is returned in case of error).

Your Python script could look something like this:

```
import sys

def main():
    # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        print >> sys.stderr,  e
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        sys.exit()
```

You could call again `main()` in case of error, but the program might not be in a state where it can work correctly again.
It may be safer to launch the program in a new process instead.

So you could write a script which invokes the Python script, gets its return value when it finishes, and relaunches it if the return value is different from 0 (which is what `sys.exit()` uses as return value by default).
This may look something like this:

```
import subprocess

command = 'thescript'
args = ['arg1', 'arg2']

while True:
    ret_code = subprocess.call([command] + args)

    if ret_code == 0:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create wrapper using subprocess(http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) which will spawn your application as a child process and track it's execution.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to catch errors, and close the old and open a new instance of the program when you do catch em.

Note that it will not always work (in cases it stops working without throwing an error).